# How to get the latest Perforce changelist in the depot for the current client spec

Tags: perforce

I want to get the latest changelist in the depot for my current client spec. This would effectively be the change that would by synced to if I did a `p4 sync` in my workspace.

I tried doing `p4 changes -s submitted -m1 -c [client-name]`, but that returns the most recent change that was submitted *via my client*.

Doing `p4 changes -s submitted -m1 //depot/path/...` will work, but I don't want to have to query the client spec to figure out what the depot path is.  Plus if there were more than one mapping I wouldn't know how to make sense of that.

It seems there must be a simple way to do this which I am missing.

**EDIT**

I did have to query the client spec, but as pointed out in the accepted answer, I could use the client spec root as the file path and didn't need to look at the view mappings.

Final solution using P4Python:

```
# Get client
clientspec = p4.fetch_client()
root = clientspec["Root"]

# Get latest changenum in client mapping
changes = p4.run("changes", "-s", "submitted", "-m1", root + "/...")
changenum = changes[0]['change']
```

Comment: Is `p4 changes -s submitted -m 1` (with no path) not suitable?

Comment: @jamesdlin - No, that gives the most recent changelist on the server, which may be some depot path that I don't have mapped to my client spec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're going to have to query your client spec to find its local root.  If you don't need to worry about `AltRoots`, then this could be:

```
p4 changes -s submitted -m 1 "$(p4 client -o | grep "^Root:" | cut -f 2)/..."
```

in bash.  Using your local client root instead of the depot path avoids the problem with multiple mappings.